# Windows Phone Performance Analysis makes game run faster. Possible reasons?

Tags: xna, performance, windows-phone-7

A XNA game I was making was running slowly on my WP7 device. However when I started it in Windows Phone Performance Analysis to find the bottleneck, the game ran smoothly on the same device.

I figured the problem out a little later, and it was an adjacency-checking function. I have optimized the function and the game works fine now.

Why was the game magically speeding up in Perf Analysis mode? Any possible explanations?

This was the code that ran faster on the Perf Analysis mode, but slow otherwise. It is a damage-dealing function in a tower defense game.

```
 foreach (Target myTarget in _targets)
 {
        for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
        {
                for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
                {
                    if (x == 0 && y == 0) continue;
                    try
                    {
                        Tile adjacent = _tiles[(int)myTarget.CurrentTile.X + x, (int)myTarget.CurrentTile.Y + y];
                        if (adjacent.Tower != null)
                        {
                            DealDamage(myTarget, adjacent.Tower);
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
 }
```

I optimized it later by checking damage for each tower instead of each target.

Comment: I don't have the knowledge to help, but maybe adding the code before and after your fix would help others.

Comment: Just to be clear, the *same* code consistently ran faster while I ran it in Perf Analysis mode. I don't understand the reasons behind this happening. The fact that I optimized the code later is irrelevant.

Comment: It might not be irrelevant, it sounds like the code you changed was fast in Per Analysis mode and not normally. Maybe you could isolate it. So if you posted before and after, the differences might be what the Performance Analysis mode does better (for whatever reason).

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Valid point. I'm adding the code.

Comment: As a random guess is the performance difference still there if you take out the try catch? I'd think the best way to find it would be to remove code until you have the smallest possible bit of code that shows the performance difference between perf mode on and off.

Comment: If it runs faster while being observed, then you probably have a side effect that occurs because of the observation. Do you have any lazy-loaded/calculated properties in there for instance?

Comment: Perhaps is a caching issue. Maybe the perfomance read the same variables as this code, but trigger some caching mechanism, so the data of the map is always on memory.

Comment: @Tei I agree. I will look into the caching mechanism in detail when I get time.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the try/catch overhead for each iteration of a potentially large nested loop was killing your performance and that the analysis tool somehow affected the exception handler overhead. You could easily test that by removing the exception handling and running normally, without the profiler.

You definitely don't want a try/catch on the inside of a tight loop. You would be much better off ensuring that you account for anything that can generate an exception within your loop via conditional checks, or at the very least put the try/catch around the loop as a whole.

Comment: Will give it a try, though I suspect this behavior has got something to do with caching.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the tool itself, nor I am an expert on compiler optimization, but the reason could lie in the line:

```
Tile adjacent = _tiles[(int)myTarget.CurrentTile.X + x, (int)myTarget.CurrentTile.Y + y];
```

What could happen here is that the a `Tile` adjacent is created on the stack, with values copied from the the right tile in `_tiles[]` (you are not using what would be a reference in C++, and I don't know if they exist in C#). Therefore, you are continuously creating and destroying a `Tile` object, and moreover, inside 2 big nested for loop. Although it's on the stack, this could definitely affect speed. What maybe happened is that the Perf Analysis mode recognized this scenario, pre-allocated a `Tile` object outside the nested loop and kept on using it through the function, avoiding the overhead of creation/destruction.

Comment: I realized this problem early on and did fix it. It did not give me a noticeable performance boost nor did it change the magical speedup on perf analysis mode.